# C: Are #define directives global?

Tags: c

I'm somewhat confused by `#define` statements. In libraries, they seem to be a means of communication across different files, with lots of `#ifdef`s and `#ifndef`s.

Having said that, I now have two files `file1.c` and `file2.c` compiled together, with `#define TEST 10` inside `file2.c`. Yet, when I use `TEST` inside `file2.c` the compiler gives the following error message:

```
'TEST' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Are `#define` directives global?

Comment: It depends where they are defined.

Comment: `#define` is a preprocessor directive - it just makes simple text substitutions at compile time - only the compilation unit and any `#include`d files will *see* a `#define`.

Comment: the (#ifndef #define #endif) trick would not work if macros were global

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`#define`s are not global, they are just a substitution where ever they are used (if declared in the same compile unit)

They are **not** globals, they are **not** symbols, they are **irrelevant** at linkage, they are only relevant at **pre-compilation**.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile unit"? How can I have `file1.c` and `file.2` in the same compile unit?

Comment: No. they are compiled separately. and hen linked together. Are you familiar with the C build process?

Comment: So `file1.c` and `file2.c` can never be in the same compile unit?

Comment: basically - no. if you want to share a macro between them, put it in a header file and include that header in both files.

Comment: @Randomblue: Think of a "compile unit" as "a c file, and all of the headers it includes, and all of the headers those include, etc, etc, etc, until no more headers". This is one "chunk" that the compiler compiles.  After the compiler compiles each c file separately, then it links those outputs togeather.

Answer (score 11):

`#define`d macros are global in that they do not follow normal C scoping rules.  The textual substitution from the macro will be applied (almost) *anywhere* the macro name appears after its `#define`. (Notable exceptions are if the macro name is part of a comment or part of a string literal.)

If you define a macro in a header file, any file that `#include`s that header file will inherit that macro (whether desired or not), unless the file explicitly undefines it afterward with `#undef`.

In your example, `file2.c` does not know about the `TEST` macro.  How would it know to pick up the `#define` from `file1.c`?  By magic?  Since macros perform textual substitution on the source code, there is no representation of them in the generated object files. `file2.c` therefore needs to know that substitution rule itself, and if you want that shared across multiple files, that `#define` needs to live in a common header file that your `.c` files `#include`.

If you're asking specifically about how many of the `#ifdef`s that you see in libraries work, many of them are likely checking against *pre-defined* macro names provided by the compilation environment.  For example, a C99 compiler defines a `__STDC_VERSION__` macro that specifies the language version; a Microsoft compiler defines an `_MSC_VER` macro. (Often these predefined macros start with leading underscores since those names are reserved for the compiler.)

Additionally, most compilers allow defining simple macros as command-line arguments.  For example, you might compile your code via `gcc -DNDEBUG file1.c` to compile `file.c` with `NDEBUG` defined to disable `assert`s.

Comment: Thx for helpful info

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody reads this later, and to add some practical information:

- Some environments like atmel, vs, or iar, allow you to define global #define directives. They basically pass these defined values to the precompiler in some commandline format.
- You can do the same in batch commands or makefiles, etc.
- Arduino always adds a board variant (usually located at hardware\arduino\variants) to all compilations. At that point you can create a new board that contains your global define directives, and use it that way. For example, you can define a mega2560(debug) board out of the original mega2560 that contains some debug directives. You will add a reference to that variant in "boards.txt", by copy pasting some text, and properly modifying it.

At the end of the day, you will have to give that global hfile or global directive to the compiler in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a file1.h and put your defines there. Then in file2.c

```
#include "file1.h"
```

easy as a pie :)